# What is the SQL Server equivalent Table Type in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

In my SQL server procedure am having a input as TVP . Is there any possible ways to achieve this in Snowflake?

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake has 3 types of semistructured data, object, json (variant) or array. depending on your usage I would suggest to look through the documentation/examples and decide which one makes most sense for you:

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/data-types-semistructured.html